# Is there any way to check if a typescript class has a property?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say i have a class like this:

```
export class Test{
  public prop: string;
}
```

and at the start, I call

```
const obj = new Test();
```

is there any way that I can see what properties I have on the Test model without assigning the properties,
I tried this but it does not work

```
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('prop'))
```

Comment: if (obj.someProp !== undefined) obj.someProp()

Comment: @TheFool what if `prop` **is defined** but it has a value of `undefined`?

Comment: "I tried this but it does not work" What happened when you tried that?

Comment: I'm getting an error "*Property 'prop' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor. (2564)*" from that code. If you fix it, then the `hasOwnProperty` check will work.

Comment: [Discussed here as wel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959488/get-properties-of-class-in-typescript/41959663)