# Get class (interface) properties in Angular 5 / TypeScript without assigning a default value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Let's pretend that I have an interface A, that I am declaring as a class by following the Angular style guide. This class has many properties, and I want to fetch them names without having to assign any value to them. How can I achieve this ?

**Class A:**

```
export class A {
  property1: string;
  property2: string;
  ...
  property30: string;
}
```

I tried with instantiating a new object from this class and calling `Object.keys` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` but this two methods return an empty array because they are ignoring undefined value properties. Is there any way to bypass this behaviour ? Or am I breaking the JavaScript/TypeScript pattern ? :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get properties of a class using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636292/get-properties-of-a-class-using-typescript)

Comment: Nop it's not a duplicate because in the link provided they are giving some default values to the properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way properties declarations work is that they are just a hint to the compiler that that property may exist at run-time. In JavaScript you don't need to declare fields, so until the field is assigned it will not exist on the object. If you initialize the field even just with `null` or `undefined` the field will appear on the object. This is the simplest way to achieve what you want.

The other way would be to use a decorator on every field. This would be more explicit but not shorter and not necessarily less error prone

Comment: The thing is that I have a lot of classes for which I want to know the properties, and I can't do that without assigning a default value. Right ?

Comment: @e.m.b In either solution, assigning a default or decorators, you will have to do something to all properties

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your compiler supports class first. And then you have to do either interface or class. Ex. if it's a class, you need to do

```
class A {
    title = ''
}
var a = new A();
console.log(a);
```

declare title as a string, `title: String = ''`. Your writing is more for the interface. Here's the output,

```
Object {
    title: ""
}
```

Yeah, I understand your question better now, without assignment, it doesn't set the properties.

```
interface B {
    title: String;
}
class A implements B {
    title = '';
}
var a = new A();
console.log(a);
```

If that's the case, a simple solution is to give some **default** value of that property. Or going through a list to manually initialize all of them based by their type.

```
class A {
    keys = {
        title: 'String'
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no way without setting a default value ?

Comment: Thanks e.m.b, interesting, this is just so interesting.

Comment: The thing is that I have a lot of classes and I am too lazy like every developer lol to assign a default value for every class properties.

Comment: try `a.constructor`, ex. `console.log(a.constructor)` from the above example

Comment: a.constructor return a function called A() that takes 0 parameters and I only have an attribute name equal to A.

Comment: you're right, sorry, that doesn't work either. Ok, I gave up :) Here's fallback, `class A { title = new String(); }`. I think the missing link is a manual initialization based on the `type`. I don't know Javascript actually doesn't do that!!