# js get list of own static properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class with static properties and I want to get a list of all property values:

```
class TimeRange {
    static ALL = 'all time'
    static MONTH = 'month'
    static WEEK = 'week'
    static DAY = 'day'
}
```

Now I want to get: `['all time', 'month', 'week', 'day']`

Comment: This doesn't look like JavaScript to me...

Comment: @AngelPolitis It is. ES2016

Comment: Node doesn't seem to think so.

Comment: @Chris There are no [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) properties in JavaScript (_yet_): _"The static keyword defines a static **method** for a class."_

Comment: Static properties are a feature proposal and can be used via Babel.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, sry. I assumed that the syntax would be the same for ES 2016

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What's your use case here? If you're looking for a way to have some properties that you can iterate through but also refer to by key, then you can just use a normal object:

```
const timeRanges = {
  ALL: 'all time',
  MONTH: 'month',
  WEEK: 'week',
  DAY: 'day'
}
timeRanges.ALL; // 'all time'
timeRanges.MINUTE; // not allowed
Object.keys(timeRanges).map(key => timeRanges[key]); // ['all time', 'month', 'week', 'day']
```

Classes are not really designed to have their properties iterated through. However, if they absolutely must be in a class, you could turn them into instance properties follow the method outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636292/get-properties-of-a-class-using-typescript):

```
class TimeRange {
  ALL = 'all time'
  MONTH = 'month'
  WEEK = 'week'
  DAY = 'day'
}
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new TimeRange()); // ['all time', 'month', 'week', 'day']
```

That's somewhat of an anti-pattern, though.

One final option you might consider would be to use a string enum:

```
enum TimeRange {
  ALL = 'all time',
  MONTH = 'month',
  WEEK = 'week',
  DAY = 'day'
}
Object.keys(TimeRange).map(key => TimeRange[key]); // ['all time', 'month', 'week', 'day']
```

(To clarify, I'm assuming you're using Typescript here based on the tags in the question. If you're not, then the comments on your original question stand. You could still use options 1 and 2 that I suggest here, but obviously without the type checking benefits.)

Comment: One use case which I'm currently struggling with is having the individual properties depend on one another. The example is I'm building a Class that has static members that build a store of API endpoints. For example, I have "/api1/", "/api2/" as two static members, and later, extensions of those endpoints are additional static members. You can't have these types of self references if you use an enum or an object, correct?

Comment: @AdamP. I think you're probably better off asking this as a separate question and outlining your situation in some more detail (preferably with an example) - it's hard to know what the right approach is given your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling there are some edge cases not handled here but

```js
class TimeRange {
    static ALL = 'all time'
    static MONTH = 'month'
    static WEEK = 'week'
    static DAY = 'day'
}

function getClassStaticProperties(constructor) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(constructor));
}

function getOwnStaticProperties(instance) {
  return getClassStaticProperties(instance.constructor);
}


const tr = new TimeRange();

// via an instance
{
  const staticProps = getOwnStaticProperties(tr);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(staticProps, null, 2));
  console.log(Object.values(staticProps));
}

// via the class
{
  const staticProps = getClassStaticProperties(TimeRange);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(staticProps, null, 2));
  console.log(Object.values(staticProps));
}
```

Comment: "I have a feeling there are some edge cases not handled here", maybe statics inherited by `extend`?

Comment: it doesn't see statics inherited by `extends` so seems to do what was asked, show "*own* static properties". It doesn't see static functions (which I was surprised by). My point about edge cases is I can probably do `TimeRange.foobar = 123` and it will start showing `foobar`. But then maybe `TimeRange.foobar` is an "own static". Or maybe if I hack the constructor with `Object.defineProperty` or something?

Comment: Ah I missed the title asked for "own" statics only. Makes me curious as to when it's preferable to avoid inherited ones, but... ok, my bad. Arguably yes, `TimeRange.foobar` is now an "own static" property.

Comment: For the methods you could use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()`, but you'd also get things like `name`, `length`, and `prototype` which are also own properties of that class, but which I guess OP didn't really want.

Answer (score 0):

I know it goes a bit beyond topic, but this is the closest i found in my research.

Like @Kaiido said, you may use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()` and **delete** the reserved properties if ancestors don't matter.

I struggled myself for class introspection and i hope it helps someone on a similar problem : ) .

```js
class MyAncestor{
  static ancestorProp1='prop a 1';
}

class MyClass extends MyAncestor{
  static myclassProp1='prop c 1';
  // Ignored by Object.keys & Object.entries 
  static myclassMethod1(){ /*...*/ }
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
}

// An other way to declare a static property & method
MyClass.myclassProp2='prop c 2';
MyClass.myclassMethod2=function(){ /*...*/ };
// Ignored by Object.keys & Object.entries
Object.defineProperty(MyClass,'myclassProp3',{get:()=>'prop c 3'})

/**
  @param {class} constructor : the class constructor
  @param {boolean} [handleAncestor] : handle inherited classes
  @return {Array<string>} the static property names
*/
const getClassStaticPropertyNames=function(constructor,handleAncestor=false){
  const props=[];
  if(handleAncestor){
    const ancestor=Object.getPrototypeOf(constructor.prototype)?.constructor;
    if(ancestor&&ancestor.name!=='Object'){
      props.push(...getClassStaticPropertyNames(ancestor,true));
    }
  }
  const exclude=[
    // remove reserved properties
    'prototype','name','length',
    // remove inherited duplicates
    ...props
  ];
  
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(constructor)
  .filter(k=>!exclude.includes(k))
  .concat(props);

};

/**
  @param {class} constructor : the class constructor
  @param {boolean} [handleAncestor] : handle inherited classes
  @return {Object} the static properties
*/
const getClassStaticProperties=function(constructor,handleAncestor=false){
  const data={};
  getClassStaticPropertyNames(constructor,handleAncestor)
  .forEach(k=>data[k]=constructor[k]);
  return data;
}

console.log('Object.keys misses "myclassMethod1" & "myclassProp3" :',Object.keys(MyClass));

console.log('Object.entries misses "myclassMethod1" & "myclassProp3" :',Object.entries(MyClass).map(e=>e[0]));

console.log('MyClass static property & method names :',getClassStaticPropertyNames(MyClass));

console.log('MyClass & ancestors static property & method names :',getClassStaticPropertyNames(MyClass,true));

console.log('MyClass static properties & methods :',getClassStaticProperties(MyClass));
```

PS : I could have used `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` or `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()` for a deeper description but the plunker would have been more complicated.