# What is a Generic Type for showing keys of the current child instance of a class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm having trouble figuring out this simple (on the surface) problem. I'm looking to create a type that has the keys of both the parent class, and the current child I'm working on. I have these classes:

```
class A {
  foo = 1;
  xoo = 'abc';

  get(){
    return {} as ?;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  bar = 2;
  zar = [1, 2, 3];

  init() {
    this.get(). // < -- should autocomplete and show both "foo" and "bar".
  }
}
```

As you can see, I would like to have this.get() return a type that keys of both the Parent and Child that are of type **number**. In this case, the autocomplete should show both "**foo**" and "**bar**" as options, but not "**init**", "**get**", "**xoo**" or "**zar**". I've for a long while tried to get this working, but I think it's just beyond my knowledge at this point. Any help in accomplishing this and understanding the solution would be massively helpful!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get properties of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636292/get-properties-of-a-class)

Comment: How should your type decide which properties to ignore? Are you literally giving those properties names beginning with `ignoreMe`?

Comment: @kaya3 I'll fix the example. They are to be ignored because they aren't a number.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should properly type `get` method:

```js
type OnlyNumbers<T> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] extends number ? Prop : never
}[keyof T]

const pickNumbers = <Obj,>(obj: Obj) =>
  (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof Obj>)
    .reduce((acc, elem) =>
      typeof obj[elem] === 'number' ? {
        ...acc,
        [elem]: obj[elem]
      } : acc, {} as Pick<Obj, OnlyNumbers<Obj>>)


class A {
  foo = 1;
  xoo = 'abc';

  get = () => pickNumbers(this)
}
```

Now we can explicitly type our `this`:

```js
class B extends A {
  bar = 2;
  zar = [1, 2, 3];

  init(this: B & A) {
    this.get().bar // ok
    this.get().foo // ok
    this.get().zar // error
  }
}

// "bar" | "foo"
type Test = keyof {
  [Prop in keyof Pick<B, OnlyNumbers<B>>]: Prop
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBA8gOwDZgHIFcC2AjKAnAZwB4AVAPhgF4YBvYGGAbQAU8B7CGASwRgGsoYNgDMYJALoAuMS3YRxMKAA8QUBABMCMBFlx4YAfhisOMaQigA3fMAC%20jAUNETgwAMZsEBEDAhc3fBg4%20FrURHDYAFYANGQAFGxR0hGRAJRUZPQwcSlQbiAAdI4ECVHpAIZaAIJ4eOVgRI4i8FFkqVkMBXhQ6uhuUHFx5W5u0YpIUJjplJkMczDg0M2JkYxQE5gKlNswAOQ6wXi7hrQd8zAFl8OjZ-NrG1IwK-eT4rcwtmYw12M0n5XGfx8cJRMaIFBBPTEFJkNqudxISrVU4MYRsNhUGAARgA3FklOjMbtytg3Ls8VkAOZQHzUOLTCh%20AKQkJxEAACy4BHatlcbkRBC0ACFFCo1JoYFUUTBsOV9NQAEx4hgALzlmMYWLGCrGAGZxBSGDwuCA2ZyCNIRQAySXpOjzDlcgrU02pAqy-QAek9Tz4Z0dBGdNPpBTRGO9vv95qDroKaq9Pvw7DwWV5vOAEYARB7MzAAD4wTNhzOgSCwEhQbyYpqie1MEycHj8QTNZhAohCsHINC6EId2GPBt2IA)

You can get rid of `A&B` in `init` but then you loose autocomplete. From the other hand you will still have autocomplete out of the class scope:

```js
class B extends A {
  bar = 2;
  zar = [1, 2, 3];

  init() {
    this.get()
  }
}

const result = new B().get() // foo | bar
```

Comment: This is really great work. I'll have to study it for a while. For the library I'm writing, though, I worry it would be too much to ask the next guy to have to include the this typing if they wanted autocomplete (this: B & A). Is there any way you can imagine this working without specifying the type of this like you did?

Comment: I did some poking around and tried Pick<this, OnlyNumbers<this>>. As you probably know, no luck. Is something like this not possible?

Comment: 90% that it is impossible to do. Seems to be that TS treats `this` as a black box

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
class A<T> {
  foo = 1;
  ignoreMeA = "abc";
  
  get() {
    type s = (this & T)
    return {} as { [p in keyof s]: s[p] extends number ? s[p] : never };
  }
}

class B extends A<B> {
  bar = 2;
  ignoreMeB = "xyz";

  init() {
    this.get().bar // has autocomplete for Number object; 
    this.get().ignoreMeA // has no autocomplete
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I appreciate this. I probably wasn't clear enough, but my hope was that the autocomplete of **this.get()** would only show **foo** and **bar**. Not that *foo* and **bar** would not have auto complete themselves. so typing: this.get(). <-- that period would then show only **foo** and **bar** as options.