# JSON.stringify for TypeScript includes hidden fields but not values for public interface

Tags: json, typescript, getter

I seem to have some basic misunderstanding of serialization in TypeScript with `JSON.stringify` and interfaces, but I am trying to design an export format to serialize some of my objects back to the server-side representation (base type data only, not methods).

I had read in several places that interfaces provide a handy means for exporting to JSON, but don't understand how that is supposed to be done.

Here's a basic example of what I tried:

```
interface PublicFoo {
  name: string,
  age: number
}

class Foo implements PublicFoo {
    private _name : string;
    private _age : number;
    private _pin : number;

    constructor(name : string, age : number, pin: number) {
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
        this._pin = pin;
    }
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
    get age() :number {
        return this._age;
    }
    get pin() : number {
        return this._pin;
    }
    serialize() : string {
        let pubFoo : PublicFoo = this;
        return (JSON.stringify(pubFoo));
    }
}
```

I was hoping that if I run this:

```
let foo = new Foo("George", 27, 3918);
console.log(foo.serialize());
```

I would get something like this:

```
{"name":"George","age":27}
```

but instead I get this:

```
{"_name":"George","_age":22,"_pin":3239}
```

showing private filed names including those I don't want to serialize and aren't in the `PublicFoo` interface.

What would be the right method to do this without having to construct the export by hand? The fact that you can just stringify the object is great since the actual objects are big and bulky...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like getters are taken into account for `stringify`.
Whether or not typescript is supposed to take the hints from interfaces to populate serialisations *using getters* automagically is a different question (knowing interfaces aren't in plain JS and so there is no default *behaviour* to inherit).

So just add a [`toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior) and change your serialise to use it:

```
toJSON = () :PublicFoo => ({name:this._name, age:this._age});

serialize = () :string => (JSON.stringify(this));
```

It's also good to remember typescript is just a typing infrastructure to help the programmer; it's still JS.
**Nothing is private**

---

To account for your comment, try using [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53995901/2518317) to get compile-time information into the runtime

```
import {keys} from 'ts-transformer-keys';

function freeze<Interface extends object>(instance :Interface) :Interface {
    let output :Interface = {} as any;
    for (let property of keys<Interface>())
        output[property] = instance[property];
    return output;
}
```

Then change `toJSON` above to be `toJSON = () :PublicFoo => (freeze<PublicFoo>(this));`

Comment: Yes I understand that such a thing doesn't provide any security, but do you know what people mean when they talk about generating JSON "from Interfaces"?  (one of Anders Hejlsberg's what's new in typescript videos" I am thinking about writing a function that takes an interface and an implementor and returns the json representing all the fields which are numbers, strings or arrays on the interface.  But I was hoping there was an easy way. . .

Comment: If you provide the generic functionality, you'll be able to use any interface you make however you like. Try what I just edited in

Comment: Thanks, this look like just what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that typescript itself provides *no runtime functionality*, which is what you are expecting here. It merely provides enforcement of type safety *at compile time*. Thus, if you want to see what your typescript will actually do, you need to look at the javascript it compiles to. Get methods are functions, which return a value when called, like any function, so naturally when you serialize the object, you will not see the values returned from such functions. How to do it? Well you will have to write the serialization method yourself I'm afraid.