# Create an object from interface with keys and values - typescript

Tags: typescript, interface

Is there any way to create an object based on an interface which use the same keys and values?

For example. I have following interface:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

and I would like to generate an object which looks like this:

```
const personFieldNames = {
  name: "name",
  age: "age",
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't make an object from an interface because the types only exist at compile time but, you can make a type from an object using `typeof`.

```
const person = {
  name: 'name',
  age: 0
}

type Person = typeof person

const john: Person = {
  name: 'john',
  age: 20
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't loop through properties of `Interface` because they are only for compile time. But what you can do, is creating an object from your `Interface` and loop over its `properties`.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const personFieldNames: Person = {
  name: "name",
  age: 123,
};

let newObject = {};

Object.keys(personFieldNames)
.forEach(key => {
    newObject = {... newObject, [key] : key};
})

console.log(newObject);
```

Output:

```
[LOG]: {
  "name": "name",
  "age": "age"
}
```

Or you can use the [ts-transformer-key](https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53995901/10691359)

Comment: This got me going to where I needed to go as a single dto row lookup and api value mapper. Thanks a bunch.