# How to check if a component has a property definition programmatically in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a property of a component in  Angular that looks like this:

```
export class CarComponent implements OnInit {
  partNumber: number;

  checkIfItHasAPartNumberProperty() {
      return this.hasAProperty('partNumber');
  }
```

What is Angular equivalent for hasAProperty to check if this class contains a definition of a property by string name, eg. "partNumber"?

It is not a question about getting value of "partNumber", or checking directly if it has property "partNumber", but check programmatically if a component has a property of a given name (by string).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894792/how-to-determine-whether-an-object-has-a-given-property-in-javascript could be helpful

Comment: @Jota.Toledo hasOwnProperty does not seem to work for Angular component properties

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30207661/1009922). The properties that have been initialized can be retrieved with `hasOwnProperty` but the others are not present in the class instance at runtime. You can see that with `console.log(this)`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan i get it. So how to do it?

Comment: @TomaszSmykowski - [One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43572554/1009922) suggests using custom transformers but I have never tried that.

Comment: @ConnorsFan It sounds like something to investigate further, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 const obj = this as object;
 obj.hasOwnProperty('prop')
```

Cast this to object and you should be able to call hasOwnProperty on it

**EDIT**
This wont work on properties that haven't been initialized. For that case (if possible in your scenario) initialize the property with null and the above code will work