# Get available properties of interface without initializing

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I'm trying to create a generic "mapping" method that can take an interface and JSON response then map the available keys to the interface. The issue I'm having is there seems no way to get the available properties of an interface without initializing them.

Is there a way to get the value of an interface without having to define it?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: No, you would be better off using a Class instead.

Comment: @Paleo I want to get the available keys for an interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript check object by type or interface at runtime with typeguards in 2020+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480160/typescript-check-object-by-type-or-interface-at-runtime-with-typeguards-in-2020)

Comment: You can use a transformer like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43572554/7647005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply switching my interfaces to a class was the solution. I am then able to create a blank instance and list out all available properties.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces and other type information (with exceptions) are not available at runtime.

However, you can define a method that deserializes a JSON string into a given type. `const myThing: IThing = JSON.parse(myJsonString);` will cast it to the type `IThing`.

If you have a class `Thing` that implements IThing, you can use `Object.keys` to iterate over the keys of an instantiated `Thing`, and match the key indices together, like `thing[key] = JSON.parse(...)[key]`

Answer (score 0):

`interface` and `types` in typescript are only checked when *compiling* (from ts to js). So,  at runtime (which runs js), there is no information about interface.

But you can implement this with use of `class` and [`reflect-metadata`](https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata) and [`decorators`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html), like [`class-transformer`](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) do.