# How to get the name of an object in an associative array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets suppose I have this object

```
var cliCorp14={
  "id":13,
  "url":"corp_longboard.html",
  "logo":"img/corp/logoLongboard.png",
  "alt":"Longboard store",
  "name":"LONGBOARD",
};
```

I want to put the text "alt" in a var. I don't want to put "Longboard store", I want to put the text "alt". How do I access to that object?

Comment: well write `var whatever='alt'`, or can 'alt' change, if it can how do you identify which key to store?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enumerate the properties of a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: That's the problem, 'alt' changes. Thank you btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object.keys(cliCorp14);
// -> ["id", "url", "logo", "alt", "name"]
```

Note that `Object.keys()` is an ES5+ method, and only available in IE9+ (although it is easy to polyfill).

Comment: I think this is the best solution. So, this Object.keys() method only works in IE9? It doesn't works in chrome or mozilla? Thank you for your time

Comment: No, it'll work in all relevant versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc. Basically just <=IE8 are the only (potentially) relevant browsers that won't support it.  See [this page](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Object.keys) for more compatibility information.

Comment: Ok, im new in this javascript thing, sorry if all of this is basic. Thank you again!

Comment: No apology necessary. If we were all pros at every possible topic, we wouldn't need SO. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var x in cliCorp14)
{
console.log(x);
}
```