# How to iterate through functions defined in a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have an object that defines a bunch of functions like this:

```
myObject = {
  "item 1": function() {
    return "I'm item 1";
  },
  "item 2": function() {
    return "I'm item 2";
  }
};
```

I want to write a function that calls all of the functions defined in this object without having to know the names of the functions or the number of functions. Is this possible?

Comment: Theoretically, you could do `for(var f in myObject){myObject[f]();}`. But the return value will be lost. What do you want to do with the return values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by first using a [for-in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to go through each of the objects properties. Then, after checking if the value is a function, you can call it.

```
for (var key in obj) {
  if (typeof obj[key] === 'function') {
    obj[key]();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In ECMAScript >=5.1 you can use the *[for .. in](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4)* construct.

```
obj = {
    test : function() {
        console.log("test called");
    }
};

for(idx in obj) {
    obj[idx]();
}
```

You may want to check that the property is actually a function.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use `Object.keys` or a for-in loop depending on your needs.

```
Object.keys(obj); // ==> ["item-1", "item-2"]
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    var fn = obj[key];
    fn();
});

// or with a for-in loop

for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        obj[key]();
    }
}
```

Using `Object.keys` is arguably a bit more clear, but the for-in loop has better browser compatibility and possibly performance. For a more general comparison of object enumeration in JavaScript, refer to this question [How do I enumerate the properties of a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object).