# Iterating over a dictionary in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, dictionary

I am fairly new to Javascript- and trying to iterate over a dictionary in Javascript. I can easily do so in python:

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    //do something
```

Is there a similar way to do the same in Javascript?

Structure I am trying to iterate over is:

```
{ 'meta.num_prod': 4,
  'meta.crtd_on': '2015-12-24T06:27:18.850Z',
  'meta.last_upd': '2015-12-24T06:46:12.888Z',
  's.103114': 
     { prod_id: '103114',
       product_type: 'normal',
       last_updated: '2015-12-24T06:28:44.281Z',
       qty: 3,
       created_on: '2015-12-24T06:27:18.850Z' },
  's.103553': 
     { prod_id: '103553',
       product_type: 'normal',
       last_updated: '2015-12-24T06:46:12.888Z',
       qty: 1,
       created_on: '2015-12-24T06:46:12.888Z' } }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enumerate the properties of a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @Pang answers there aren't that extensive. A little old too.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are multiple ways to this one standard way is using Object.keys:

You can do

- [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [Array.Prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
   console.log(key + " " + obj[key]);
});
```

If you are using jQuery you can use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method like this:

```js
$.each({ name: "John", lang: "JS" }, function( k, v ) {
  console.log( "Key: " + k + ", Value: " + v );
});
```

Or you can use a [for...in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), but most people I know don't use them nowadays due to better alternatives.

```js
for (var prop in obj) {
  console.log("obj." + prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
}
```

If you ever end up wanting to complicate things you can use [es6 generators](http://www.2ality.com/2015/03/es6-generators.html) like this to get syntax more akin to python:

```
// The asterisk after `function` means that
// `objectEntries` is a generator
function* objectEntries(obj) {
    let propKeys = Reflect.ownKeys(obj);

    for (let propKey of propKeys) {
        // `yield` returns a value and then pauses
        // the generator. Later, execution continues
        // where it was previously paused.
        yield [propKey, obj[propKey]];
    }
}

let jane = { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe' };
for (let [key,value] of objectEntries(jane)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
// Output:
// first: Jane
// last: Doe
```

Comment: How is your answer "more extensive" then the one in the question Pang mentioned? There's also nothing new in it... And as Ajay is a beginner links to some **good** documentation should also be added.

Comment: @Andreas There are 8 answers that all have `for...in` loops and nothing else. And I'll add documentation thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: `for...in`, `Object.keys`, `$.each`, some custom methods (using `for...in`) and also one with a reference to `underscore.js`.

Comment: @Andreas $.each isn't even mentioned on the whole page. Object.keys doesn't have an example, and most people don't even use underscore anymore; they use Lodash. It's an old thread, and I'm trying to help a guy see some more options without having to dig. Is there a problem with that?

Comment: Now THAT's extensive! Thanks a tonne! Even though I was able to work around with @Pang's link!

Comment: `Or you can use a for...in loop, but most people I know don't use them nowadays due to better alternatives.` what, if anything, is wrong with for loop? It appears to be simpler.

Answer (score 5):

EcmaScript 2017 has `Object.entries` that comes in handy in situations like this one. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const obj = { 
    'meta.num_prod': 4,
    'meta.crtd_on': '2015-12-24T06:27:18.850Z',
    'meta.last_upd': '2015-12-24T06:46:12.888Z',
}

Object.entries(obj).forEach(function([key, value]) {
   console.log(`${key} ${value}`);
});
```

Output:

> meta.num_prod 4
>   meta.crtd_on 2015-12-24T06:27:18.850Z
>   meta.last_upd 2015-12-24T06:46:12.888Z