# How to populate options with array in Javascript using keys as values and values as content?

Tags: javascript, arrays, drop-down-menu

I have a situation similar to this [JavaScript - populate drop down list with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895082/javascript-populate-drop-down-list-with-array), with one exception. I need the keys to populate the values, not the values.

For example, my array is this:

`var months = {"":"--None--", "jan":"January", "feb":"February", "mar":"March"};`

In the article mentioned the function works great, but I need the value to be different from the content. Here's my altered code:

```
var monthOptions = document.getElementById("month");
function loadMonths(months){
    monthOptions.innerHTML = '';
            
    for(var i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
        var opt =  months[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value =  months[i].keys();
        monthOptions.appendChild(el);
     }
}
```

My HTML:

`<select name="month" id="month" required></select>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `el.textContent = opt` is the content setting what you searching for.
How to iterate over your dictonary `months` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34448724/iterating-over-a-dictionary-in-javascript) and insert the element setting like this:

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(months)){
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = value;
    el.value =  key;
    monthOptions.appendChild(el);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!