# Javascript array.forEach with custom keys not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have dynamically generated array

```
var userData = new Array();
var userHash = "HashCode123";

// now I push object to that array:
userData[userHash].username = "Ferdo";
userData[userHash].ban = 0;
```

Console returning this values:

```
userData
[] //why this is not array of object(s)?

userData[hash]
Object {username: "Ferdo", ban: 0}
```

I need run `userData.forEach()` but I can't because array is empty? Thank you for help.

Comment: Arrays in JavaScript are objects, so you can give them string property names like that, but none of  the array methods will pay attention to those. Only numeric properties are included in iteration etc.

Comment: Arrays are not hashmaps.

Comment: http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 3):

`forEach` only iterates over **elements** of an array. Only properties whose property name has a numeric value that is between 0 and 2<sup>32</sup>-2 are considered to be elements of the array.

`"HashCode123"` doesn't fulfill this criteria. If you want arbitrary "key" names, you can use an object and iterate over that instead ([How do I enumerate the properties of a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/85992/218196)).

Answer (score 1):

When adding string keys to an array, it's 'transforms' into an object (that's not fully accurate, but you'll get the idea with that).

An array, which is iterable, can only have numeric keys.

If you want to iterate over an object, you need to either use `for let item in my_object`

Here's how I like to iterate over objects though.

```
const keys = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'];
let fruits = [];

keys.forEach(x => fruits[x] = `${x} is a fruit`);

// now we have fruits.apple, fruits.banana, fruits.orange
// Since it's now an object you'll need to get the keys and iterate over that

const fruit_keys = Object.keys(fruits);
fruit_keys.forEach(x => console.log(fruits[x]));
```

And to see it in action, here's a fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/scheda/4n0r5zmy/

Comment: Don't you mean to make `fruits` an object instead of an array?

Comment: Normally I would, yes. But in the example L. Dave posted, his was specifically an array, so that's what I used in my example.

Comment: But using an array gives the wrong impression. If you are not using an array as an array then you shouldn't use it. Don't repeat the mistakes the OP makes. After all, they are here to get "proper" solutions.

Comment: I completely agree. Just trying to stick with what the user was originally doing to make the point of needing to use Object.keys to get string key names.