# How to check if an object is a "sub-object" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, oop, object

I am stuck on the algorithm at FreeCodeCamp.
Basically, if I have an `object1{a:1,b:2,c:3}` and have another `object2{a:1,b:2}`.
How do I check if the object2 is a sub-object of the object1?

Comment: `Object1.hasOwnProperty(Object2)` ?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Do you need to check for presence of the exact ob2 in ob1 or if all the elements of ob2 are present in ob1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the properties of object B and check whether each of them is contained in object A and has the same value.

Pseudo code:

```
isSubset(A, B):
  for each property name as pName of B:
    if A contains property with name pName:
      if B[pName] equals A[pName]:
        continue
    return false
  return true
```

See [How do I enumerate the properties of a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/85992/218196) for as a start.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var object1 = {a:1,b:2,c:3};
var object2 = {a:1,b:2};

function isSubObject(object1, object2) {
 for (var key in object2) {
   // stop if the key exists in the subobject but not in the main object
 if (object2.hasOwnProperty(key) && !object1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
return false;
}
}
 return true;
}

document.write('is subobject? ' + isSubObject(object1, object2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function

```js
var o1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
var o2 = { a: 1, b: 2 }

var r = Object.keys(o2).every(e => o1[e] == o2[e])

document.write(r); // sub-object
```