# How to push variables value inside for loop array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

How to push variable a1, a2, a3, a4 values inside for loop array.

```
var a1 = 100, a2 = 400, a3 = 700, a4 = 800;
var arr= [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    arr.push("a"+i);
}
alert(arr);
```

The **result** is **a1,a2,a3,a4** instead of **100,400,700,800**.

Comment: It is not possible in this way. But have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object) discussion maybe it fits in your context

Comment: the simple way is to make a array instead of a1,a2...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Eval for the solution of the problem.

```js
 var a1 = 100, a2 = 400, a3 = 700, a4 = 800;
        var arr= [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            arr.push(eval("a"+i));
        }
        alert(arr);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: But wait! Douglas Crockford says `eval` is evil! /s :D

Answer (score 1):

```
var a1 = 100, a2 = 400, a3 = 700, a4 = 800;
var arr= [];
arr.push(a1,a2,a3,a4);
alert(arr);
```

Comment: your solution is fine for less numbers of variables. but i have more than 100 variable set, so not possible to push statically variables in array.

Comment: u have specified 4 vars thats why I provided this solution

Answer (score 1):

You can do without eval by using a map store your variables.

```
var map = { a1: 100, a2: 400, a3: 700, a4: 800 };
var arr = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    arr.push(map["a" + i]);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: whats the common difference btn **map** and **eval**. what should use in my app.

Comment: `eval` should be avoided at all cost, most people will never consider using `eval`. It has bad performance and, while not in your case, is usually a security risk. Read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil . Use the `map`, its a valuable data structure.

Comment: A map simply "maps" a key to a value. In this case a key would be `a1` and the value `100`. Now I can ask the map for a key and it will return a value. You can also access `a1`'s value like so `map.a1`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `window` object for accessing global variables.

```js
var a1 = 100,
    a2 = 400,
    a3 = 700,
    a4 = 800;
    arr = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    arr.push(window['a' + i]);
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```