# Javascript JSON get object name and values

Tags: javascript, json

I have this object

```
 {
     "Test1": {"name":"Joe","age":"20"},
     "Test2": {"name":"Jay","age":"21"},
     "Test3": {"name":"Jay","age":"22"}
 }
```

How can I get the object name e.g `Test1`, the value of name e.g `Joe` and value of age e.g `20` in a loop?

Something like this

```
 for(myVar){
     var Objectkeyname;
     var Objectname;
     var Objectage;
 }
```

I've been searching an hour, still no luck to find the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do something like this in your ajax.                                                                                                              for(var i in data)
{   var name = data[i]["name"];  var age= data[i]["age"]; }

Comment: Also this one: [How do I enumerate the properties of a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/85992/218196)

Comment: @Shahbaz: Ajax is a way of communicating with a server. That has nothing to do with accessing an object.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks I got the answer.