# How to access nested data in json string in typescript

Tags: json, typescript

I have this json structure an can't find a way to access the data values(data1, data2 and date), i'd like to have those values in an array than i can sort by date:

```
{
"07" : {
  "07" : {
    "data1" : "-1",
    "data2" : "test",
    "date" : "1995-07-07"
  },
  "08" : {
    "data1" : "1",
    "data2" : "test",
    "date" : "1995-07-08"
  },
  "09" : {
    "data1" : "-1",
    "data2" : "test",
    "date" : "1995-07-09"
  },
  "10" : {
    "data1" : "-1",
    "data2" : "test",
    "date" : "1995-07-10"
  }
},
"08" : {
  "07" : {
    "data1" : "1",
    "data2" : "test",
    "date" : "1995-08-07"
  },
  "08" : {
    "data1" : "1",
    "data2" : "test",
    "date" : "1995-08-08"
  },
  "09" : {
    "data1" : "1",
    "data2" : "test",
    "date" : "1995-08-09"
  }
}
}
```

Because my keys aren't defined as constant i don't know what they'll be in advance.

Comment: which keys wont you know exactly?

Comment: The "08", "07", "09".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polyfill for [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
const reduce = Function.bind.call(Function.call, Array.prototype.reduce);
const isEnumerable = Function.bind.call(Function.call, Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable);
const concat = Function.bind.call(Function.call, Array.prototype.concat);
const keys = Reflect.ownKeys;

if (!Object.values) {
    Object.values = function values(O) {
        return reduce(keys(O), (v, k) => concat(v, typeof k === 'string' && isEnumerable(O, k) ? [O[k]] : []), []);
    };
}

if (!Object.entries) {
    Object.entries = function entries(O) {
        return reduce(keys(O), (e, k) => concat(e, typeof k === 'string' && isEnumerable(O, k) ? [[k, O[k]]] : []), []);
    };
}
```

Code:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(myObject))
        {
            for (const [key2, value2] of Object.entries(value))
            {
                value2.data1;
                value2.data2;
                value2.date;
            }
        }
```

Instead Object.entries you can enumerate object like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object).

```
for (var key in myObject)
{
    for (var key2 in myObject[key])
    {
        myObject[key][key2].data1;
        myObject[key][key2].data2;
        myObject[key][key2].date;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. Exactly what i wanted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @loic13 If this is true, then you should accept answer. Check icon at the top left of the answer. Since you are new on SO: you should also upvote ALL answers that helped you (up arrow).

Comment: I'll give you an upvote anyway. It's a more elegant solution than mine I feel

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the key names from your json as an Array by calling the method:

```
keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(jsonObj);
```

In your example this will return an array `['07', '08']` to get the actual objects from the name you can call:

```
keys.forEach((key) => {
    objects = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(jsonObj, key)
})
```

And then you can find the names of the keys of these objects and repeat

```
objects.forEach((object) => {
    keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object);
})
```